# Fetching images from a database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am basically trying to create a Purchase page that allows users to browse through a collection of image files stored in a database and select one or more images for purchase. I have been able to upload the images into the database but do not know how to fetch them and display them on the Purchase page.
My table looks like this

```
Column               Type          Null       Default

ID                   int(11)       No   
ArtName              tinytext      No   
ArtDescription       text          No   
ArtistName           tinytext      No   
ArtistDescription    text          No   
Price                bigint(11)    No   
FileName             varchar(44)   No   
ImgFile              longblob      No
```

My purchase page so far :
The purchase page is currently called catalog.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$_SESSION['currentpage']="catalog.php" ;
$artist = $_REQUEST['artist'] ;
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','SouravBasuRoy','2525','MyteraArt');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `paintings` WHERE `ArtistName` = '$artist'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>Painting Name : " . $row['ArtName'] . "<br>" . "Artist Name : "  .  $row['ArtistName'] . "<br>" .  "Price : " . $row["Price"] . "</p><br>" ;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Catalog | Mytera Art</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="login">
<?php
$username = $_COOKIE['username'] ;
if ($username =="")
{
echo '<form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
<label>Login</label>
<label for="Username">Username :<input type="text" name="username"></label>
<label for="Password">Password :<input type="password" name="password"></label>
<input type="submit">
</form>' ;
}
else
{
echo '<form action="logout.php">Logged in as : ' . $_COOKIE["username"] . ' ' . '<input  type="submit" value="Logout"></form>' ;
}
?>
</section>
<header>
<h1>Mytera Art</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="loggedin.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="catalog.php">Catalog</a></li>
<li><a href="purchase.php">Purchase</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<aside>
<ol>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Amedeo Modigliani">Amedeo Modigliani</a></li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Claude Monet">Claude Monet</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Edvard Munch">Edvard Munch</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Gustav Klimt">Gustav Klimt</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Hans Holbein">Hans Holbein</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Kazimir Malevich">Kazimir Malevich</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Pablo Picasso">Pablo Picasso</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Paul Cézanne">Paul Cézanne</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Peter Paul Rubens">Peter Paul Rubens</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Pierre-Auguste Renoir">Pierre-Auguste Renoir</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Pontormo">Pontormo</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Thomas Eakins">Thomas Eakins</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Titian">Titian</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Vincent van Gogh">Vincent van Gogh</li>
<li><a href="catalog.php?artist=Wang Meng">Wang Meng</li>
</ol>
</aside>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I need the code that fetches the images based on the Artist name and displays it on the screen.
One particular artist may have more than one image.
The images are stored in www/images folder so if there is a way I can just use the file name of the image while not actually fetching the file itself would I think be easier and I would lie=ke to do it this way. But whatever you suggest. This is a for college project.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any problems here, where did you stuck at?

Comment: why not uploading the files in a folder, and keep only the "location" in the database, such that when you write `site.com\images\<image_name>.<format>` you see the image, note: better "hash" the image name when uploading so you don't run into having the same file twice

Comment: Make sure you're loading `session_start();` (*Yeah yeah, I know it's hidden somewhere*), but if it's not, **do**.

Comment: I want to SELECT rows based on the $artistname and display the images as thumbnails that onclick enlarge with image information(such as artist name, price etc) displayed along side.

Comment: @ŢîganIon could you give me the code for that. I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: I doubt that anyone will write the code for you. Just check the MySQL syntax and find out how to select something from your table. You can come back later with a specific question.

Comment: ok alright. could you just tell me what functions I should use. I'll figure out the rest myself. [Actually been doing this nonstop for the past 3 days, don't have any more energy left :(] just a lil' help is all I ask. :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried using session but $_SESSION['username'] never saved the username. I was all for using session but me it didn't work so I reverted to using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I already pointed out in the comments that this question is not very specific, though you can look on the following manuals and documentations for further information in order to do that, what you want to archive.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/

To pull your images and pictures from your database, a **SELECT** query is what you are looking for. Fetching them shouldn't be an issue since there is almost nothing to fetch if you precisely query the required information. You might need to loop through your result, however.

For querying the image in your table, your query may look as follows:

```
SELECT ImgFile FROM yourtable WHERE ArtName = 'yourname'
```

You should also consider using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) since mysql_* is now deprecated.